# Unity 3d models don't appear when exporting to android app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, vuforia, 3d-model

I've been working on an AR application using unity3d with vuforia
whenever a marker is detected (image) it must show a specific 3d model related to that image
It works totally perfect in unity but when I export the app as .apk and run it on my android device, models don't appear, although it detects the marker *I checked that by printing out a specific sentence related to each marker*
I also tried before to load some models from the unity assets and it also worked fine and appeared on my android device
I'm using 3ds models each one is about 23 MB size
I thought it might be because of the size of app so **I tried to place only one model but that didn't work either..**
any solutions for that?

Comment: So it worked with some models and didn't worked with some?

Comment: actually I didn't try my app with different models but I followed the same steps for detecting markers and loading models in a different app for testing and it was working  very well. However I test my app with some game objects like cubes and spheres and it worked!